# ListBox: Compute next item's location

Tags: wpf, listbox

Does ListBox or WPF in general provide a way to compute the position of the next item that will be added to it, before actually adding it? So for example I have got 7 elements in my ListBox and I want to know where the 8th item will go relative to the ListBox bounds.

All my items are of the same type and share the same `DataTemplate`. I know we can do complex math by taking into account item size, margins, padding, scroll setting etc. and finally determine where the next item is supposed to go, but I'm looking for a built-in method that would be more reliable and robust than my maths.

Comment: Visual positioning in general? Probably not. There are alot of things like collection sorting and filtering that make sure you can't even rely on the 8th item to appear in the 8th spot (or at all) and then there is the `ItemsPanel` which might come with its special layout rules, style triggers messing with things and so on. Only if you present a very special case where all the extras don't apply, there might be a solution - but you ask a pretty general question with not so many details.

Comment: @grek40: Thanks for the input. I agree that there are minute details involved in deciding the placement of an item, but then our ListBox does have access to all those details (and will, at some point, actually use them to compute the position). I was just looking if we had access to that computational logic in the form of a public function. Looks like there isn't.

Comment: How do you want add an item and where you want to get this location information?

Comment: @Rekshino: This is basically a drag-n-drop scenario. I'm using an adorner to give a visual cue to the user about where the item will be placed. As user moves the dragged objects on the destination ListBox (the `DragOver` event), I move the adorner to top-left of the item under the mouse. Now when user moves mouse to the end of the list, i.e. AFTER the last list item, I want to know the top-left of the item that WILL BE generated upon Drop.

Comment: Actually you can get the size of existing ListBoxItems and approximate the added one, or? Another way, which is tricky is to add for a moment and remove an invisible item and get the information for them through ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator

Comment: @Rekshino: Yep. It is the first approach that I'm currently doing (approximating it based on last item's position). The second approach is too risky and I think WPF doesn't run Measure/Arrange passes until the item is actually visible. Anyway, I was looking for a more "built-in" way which I think isn't there.